# Symfony2 3-ary relations

Tags: orm, doctrine, symfony

Using Symfony2 and orm.yml files to map the entities into the database how can I create a 3-ary relationship between entities A,B,C that result in a D table that contain A_PrimaryKey, B_PrimaryKey, C_PrimaryKey the relation between the entities are this:

A-B manytomany 
A-C manytomany 
B-C manytomany

Comment: Did you try creating many-to-one/one-to-many relationships like you would with any other relation? This relation is not supported naturally I guess!

Comment: I tried to but as I did it it failed. Can you indicate me how would you do it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, your basic model would look like this:

```
A 1:n D
B 1:n D
C 1:n D
```

The yml for A would look like this:

```
Acme\TestBundle\Entity\A:
    type: entity
    # ...
    oneToMany:
        products:
            targetEntity: D
            mappedBy: d
```

You can just repeat this with B and C. For D, it would look something like this:

```
Acme\TestBundle\Entity\D:
    type: entity
    # ...
    manyToOne:
        a:
            targetEntity: A
            inversedBy: as
            joinColumn:
                name: a_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        b:
            targetEntity: B
            inversedBy: bs
            joinColumn:
                name: b_id
                referencedColumnName: id
        c:
            targetEntity: C
            inversedBy: cs
            joinColumn:
                name: c_id
                referencedColumnName: id
```

Give it a try. Maybe try to map A and D first. If this works, continue with B. So you are more likely to catch errors on the way!

Comment: this was the result when running  php app/console doctrine:schema:update --force : [PDOException]                                                                                                                                         
  SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1075 Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key

Comment: Its working fine now. Thanks. The error was due to a old table.

Comment: How would it be if the relations between entities A,B,C were:      A-B onetoone A-C onetomany B-C onetomany